# Approximation of a hypergeometirc-like distribution

Tags: limits, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, approximation, hypergeometric-function

Fix $0<\varepsilon<1$. For $m\in\mathbb{N}$,
let $$c_m=\max\left\{\frac{{m-1\choose s-1}{m\choose k-s}}{{2m\choose k}}:\;k=1,2,\dots,2m(1-\varepsilon)\;\mbox{and}\;s=1,2,\dots,k\right\}$$ Prove that $c_m\to0$ as $m\to\infty$.

I have made an initial attempt as follows:

Note that
\begin{align*}
\frac{{m-1\choose s-1}{m\choose k-s}}{{2m\choose k}}&=\frac{{2m-1\choose k-1}}{{2m\choose k}}\cdot\frac{{m-1\choose s-1}{m\choose k-s}}{{2m-1\choose k-1}}\\
&=\frac{k}{2m}{k-1\choose s-1}\prod_{j=1}^{s-1}\frac{m-s+j}{2m-s+j}\cdot\prod_{\ell=1}^{k-s}\frac{m-k+s+\ell}{2m-k+\ell}\\
&<\frac{k}{2m}{k-1\choose s-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{s-1}\left(\frac{m}{2m-s}\right)^{k-s}\\
&\le\frac{k}{2m}{k-1\choose \frac{k-1}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}\left(\frac{2m}{2m-s}\right)^{k-s}\\
&\sim\frac{k}{2m}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}(k-1)^{1/2}}\left(\frac{2m}{2m-s}\right)^{k-s},
\end{align*}
where the approximation follows by using Stirling's formula.

I have no idea about how to continue the proof. It seems not like it will achieve the goal.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: By analyzing the change as you increase $s$ by $1$ note that $c_m$ is maximized around $s=k/2$ and the result follows.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. In fact, ${m-1\choose s-1}{m\choose k-s}$ attains its maximum at $s=\lfloor\frac{mk}{2m+1}\rfloor$.

Comment: Isn't it what I said - around $k/2$ (for large $m$)? When $k$ is even, it's $k/2-1$ and when $k$ is odd it's $k/2-1/2$. Now plug these value instead of $s$ and the result will follow.